# How to calculate $f(x)$ in this question?

Tags: functions

I have a quation regarding composite functions.

if $f\left( \dfrac{x^2+1} x \right)=\dfrac{x^4+1}{x^2}$, then what is $f(x)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:
$$\left(\frac{x^2+1} x\right)^2=\frac{x^4+2x^2+1}{x^2}=\frac{x^4+1+2x^2}{x^2}$$
Alternatively you have $$\frac{x^2+1} x = x + \frac 1 x \\\frac{x^4+1}{x^2} = x^2 + \frac 1 {x^2}$$

Comment: $f(x)=x^2-2$? true?

Comment: @Jamaisavenir Yes,it's true.

Answer (score 5):

Hint: Solve $u=(x^2+1)/x$ for $x$ and then substitute $x=x(u)$ into $f((x^2+1)/x)=f(u)=\frac{x(u)^4+1}{x(u)^2}$.

It is important to note that $x\neq 0$ must hold. A useful hint is also that $x(u)^2=ux-1$ and similarly $x(u)^4=(ux-1)^2=u^2x^2-2ux+1=u^2(ux-1)-2ux+1$.

Comment: Caveat: how do you guarantee that it's the only solution (if it's only, and it's doubtful).

Comment: @xsnl: As far as I see there should be two solutions.

Comment: I mean, there's obviously only two polynomial solutions, and there're a lot of other functions besides polynomials. Why there's no other analytic solutions, for example?

Comment: @xsnl: Hmm, that is really an excellent question. Do you have any non-polynomial candidate? They should be all related to the polynomial in some way.